# npm start fails to run

Tags: npm, npm-start

why does npm start fails to run whenever I restart my MacBook? Is there any code that I would have to run before? Please help.

This is the results I get whenever I try....

```
Debugger attached.
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path /Users/somprey/Desktop/demo/package.json
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/somprey/Desktop/demo/package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/somprey/.npm/_logs/2020-10-11T03_08_40_658Z-debug.log
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
SYLVESTERs-MBP:demo somprey$
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZWaS.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

[npm start](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/start.html) triggers the start script inside package.json. As per the error message, your folder doesnt contain the package.json file.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear from the error log that the folder not contains the package.json. make sure you are running the script npm run start from the folder which contain package.json.