# Failed to start npm start

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-start

I am trying to run my React project, but I am not able to run it. The project contains typescript enabled with eslint. I tried to solve the issue with the help of previously asked questions [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64300327/npm-start-fails-to-run), but that did not work for me.

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! slipstream-frontend@0.3.0 lint: `eslint --ext js,ts,tsx src`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the slipstream-frontend@0.3.0 lint script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ROHIT AGGARWAL\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-12T06_02_13_786Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! slipstream-frontend@0.3.0 prestart: `npm run lint`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the slipstream-frontend@0.3.0 prestart script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ROHIT AGGARWAL\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-12T06_02_15_471Z-debug.log
```

I have tried to delete package.json file and then

```
npm cache clean
npm install
```

That didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this might happen,
Start with  commands in terminal

npm unit react-app app_name

cd app_name

npm start

Comment: I think you are talking about npm init @Shruti Pandey